# calling webservice on pageload using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

i have a function which i wanted to call in pageload to get the data in the page.I tried to call a webservice to get data using ajax.But doesnt return success.

here is my code

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script",    "myFunction();", True)
```

and

here is the ajax call

```
function myFunction() {
var url = "WebService.asmx/GetData";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: "{'Name':test}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (response) {

    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error getting Data');
    }
});
```

}

always showing 'error getting Data' alert

Comment: Check the error message. You can use error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }

Comment: Is it a cross domain request?

Comment: xhr.status=12019 and thrownError=unknown